# How to REJECT Facebook login process from within the app code?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

How do I abort the "login with Facebook" process from within an app?

Currently, I have a properly implemented FB login process, I'm getting an OAuth token, everything's fine... Except that in some cases I need to REJECT the login from my site's end; let's say the user was banned. Currently, I'm stuck with the proper token, and the user sees my app on their "authorized apps" list.

How can I inform Facebook that my app would like to invalidate the token and revoke its own permissions?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/permissions/request-revoke